# Issue Testing the DateTimePickerModal with Jest & React Native Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo, react-native-testing-library

I am trying to write unit tests for the [React Native Modal DateTime Picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) using Jest and the [React Native Testing Library](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/getting-started). I've passed in 3 (what I believe are) standard RN props:

```
accessible: true,
accessibilityLabel: testLabel,
testID: testLabel,
```

Here are my tests:

```
fireEvent(dobField, 'handleCalendarPress');
const calendarPicker = wrapper.getByTestId('BDD--ThirdPartyComp--DateTimePickerModal');
fireEvent(calendarPicker, 'onConfirm', ageOver18);
```

The `dobField` is my custom input field that I've created, and when it is "pressed", I can find the modal by the `testID` that I've added. However, that 3rd condition that fires the event to `onConfirm`, I am getting this error:

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: this._picker.current.setNativeProps is not a function]
```

I've read the RN docs ([link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html)) on "direct manipulation" that talk about setting/using the `native props`. However, it seems like that's something that should be implemented on the modal/lib itself, not from my side?

So my questions are:

1. Does anyone have any experience writing tests for this third party component?
2. Does anyone have more info they could share on what the TypeError means?
3. Is there a better way to write unit tests for this modal?
4. Are there props/pieces that I'm missing to be able to properly interact with the component via Jest?

Comment: did you ever find an solution to your issue? i am running into something similar with some of my tests

Comment: I did not. I submitted an issue to the dev and this is what he responded with:

```
Honestly, I've not been actively using and testing this library for years now, so I'm not sure what testing strategy is the best here.

Under the hood this library is using @react-native-community/datetimepicker. Do you mind checking if that library itself is testable or if the issue is happening just on this component?
```

This response was back in early Feb. 2020.

We ended up moving away from using this package because both front-end unit & automation tests (Appium) could not interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `react-native-datepicker` and getting the same `this._picker.setNativeProps is not a function` error. I fixed it with mocking `DatePickerIOS`, since `react-native-datepicker` uses `DatePickerIOS` for IOS date picker.

```
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS.ios.js', () => {
  const React = require('React');
  return class MockPicker extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('DatePicker', {date: '21.07.2020'});
  }
 };
});
```